# How can i load a string from js to a json file

Tags: javascript, json

How can I change a value in my json (JSValue) using js! Basically, how can I change JSValue to the var Value using js?

**JS**

```
var Value = 1 + 1
```

**JSON**

```
{
  "DATA": [
    {
      "JSValue": "0"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `yourJSONObj.DATA[0].JSValue = Value` ?

Comment: @sweaver2112 yes...and then stringify it to make it into JSON!

Comment: do you mean key ["JSValue"]or value [0] ?

Comment: Well, if it's *actually* JSON (which is a *string*) then you'll need to use `var yourJSONObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);`, use @sweaver2112's code, then use `JSON.stringify(yourJSONObj)` to get it back to JSON (which again, is a string).

Comment: Because, [There is no such thing as a JSON Object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to assign the value to the right property.

If your JSON is in a string, you can use `JSON.parse(string)` to read it, and you can convert it back to JSON with `JSON.stringify(json)`.

```js
//// Example 1

const json = {
  "DATA": [
    {
      "JSValue": "0"
    }
  ]
};

const Value = 8;

json.DATA[0].JSValue = Value; // set the value here

console.log(json);

//// Example 2

const json2 = JSON.parse('{"DATA":[{"JSValue":"0"}]}'); // from raw JSON

json2.DATA[0].JSValue = Value; // set the value here

console.log(JSON.stringify(json2)); // back to raw JSON
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign a JSON to the Data like below

> > var Value = 2;
> >     var json={"DATA": [{ "JSValue": "0" }]};

then assign the value to the json using:

> > json["DATA"][0]["JSValue"]= Value

This will assign the valu to the JSValue and change it to 2

to get the value for the JSON use

> > JSON.stringify(json)